# Why is there no play button in android browser on HTML5 video?

Tags: html

In iPhone a play button appears on a video automatically, like here:

[image]

Why is there no such thing in android? If i use a custom play button for both devices it will appear on top of the iphone plat button

any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Android doesn't display the play button. A workaround this might be to detect if the user is coming to your website through iPhone or Android. Have a look at [this](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/detect_apple_iphone_user_web_site_server.html) to see you to do that. You can then show the button only if the user comes to the website through Android.

You will also have to manually play the video on Android.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```